# Push Notification Console not loading

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-arrow

Anyone know of an issue with Appcelerator's Arrow push notification service? As of today, that part of the console won't load. (Clicking the "Send Push Notification" button.) That page hangs and won't load the content/form. Javascript error:

```
afterRender — controller.js:34:310593TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new u[this.options.view](this.options)')
```

Comment: That console has been having issues for quite some time.  The list of sent notifications will only show notifications from 3 months ago.  I opened a ticket about 2 weeks ago, but no progress yet.

The good news is that the problems seem to be limited to the UI; the ACS push notification service itself is working still.

Comment: @JasonPriebe What's the JIRA ticket URL you reported this under?

Comment: No JIRA ticket -- just a support case (00009293)